# Rendering Emoji with PIL

Tags: python, unicode, python-imaging-library, emoji

I am trying to make images out of tweets, however some of them contain [Emojis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji). I am using **PIL** to render my images and the [Symbola](http://users.teilar.gr/~g1951d/) font.

The text is in unicode utf-8 encoding and the Symbola font does include the emojis. Here is an abridged version of the code:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw
text = u"\U0001f300" #CYCLONE emoji
image = Image.new("RGBA", (100,100), (255,255,255))
font = ImageFont.truetype("Symbola.ttf", 60, encoding='unic')
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
draw.text((0,0), text, (0,0,0), font=font)
image.save("Test.png")
image.show()
```

This just renders and image with two rectangles instead of the emoji

Would appreciate any help or ideas.

Thanks!

**EDIT:** As falsetru pointed out, this code does run in Ubuntu, however it doesn't run on Windows or on Mac. Any ideas?

Comment: With your code, I've got cyclone image. I used `Symbola.ttf` as font_path, `72` as font_size. I ran it with Python 2.7.3 in Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: You are right, Any ideas why it doesn't work on Windows or Mac?

Comment: The font definitely works under Windows.  I can see the cyclone symbol using the font in Word for example.

Comment: Does PIL work with "unicode codepoints"?  Or "UTF-8"?  With the latter, I would expect to see hex `F09F8C80`.

Comment: This also works for me on macos.

Comment: Still does not work on Windows (issue: https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/1774), however a potential workaround is to generate the emoji with ImageMagick instead: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52128951/how-to-render-emojis-as-images-in-python-under-windows

Comment: somebody has a workaround for rendering whatsapp emojis?

Answer (score 2):

If the symbol CYCLONE u"\U0001f300" (I download a Symbola.tff from web) then is a very simple to use with PIL:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont, ImageFilter

#configuration
font_size=36
width=500
height=100
back_ground_color=(255,255,255)
font_size=36
font_color=(0,0,0)
unicode_text =u"\U0001f300"
im  =  Image.new ( "RGB", (width,height), back_ground_color )
draw  =  ImageDraw.Draw ( im )
unicode_font = ImageFont.truetype("Symbola.ttf", font_size)
draw.text ( (10,10), unicode_text, font=unicode_font, fill=font_color )
im.show()
```

Take a look at [this](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imagefont.htm)

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug in Pillow, see [#1774](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/1774) or [#3777](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/3777). This should now be fixed in version 6.1 of Pillow with [PR#3780](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/pull/3780), but only for Python 3.x.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to write symbols with your original font, you can do this by merging your font with `Symbola.ttf` or any emojis font. You can merge the two fonts using `fontforge` (https://fontforge.org/).

start `fontforge`, open up your main font,

Click menu: `element`->`merge fonts` and choose your emoji font (`Symbola.ttf`).
answer `no` for any popup dialog.

optionally change your new font's name: `element`->`font info`.

finally go to `file`->`generate fonts` when done and save it as `ttf` (TrueType).

Now, you can use your generated font to draw text with emojis!