# Working example of drawing non-ascii character with PIL?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, emoji

I tried [Rendering Emoji with PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17353619/rendering-emoji-with-pil)

with

```
unicode_text = u"\U0001f44d"
"You may give a Fake " + unicode_text + "card as you swap.",
```

[image]

I found this open issue.

https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/1774

I have the characters ✨ I would like to render in a string using PIL drawing text.

Comment: First please provide an executable example. Second, it works on my computer.

Comment: What Python version are you using? Does it with work Python 3?