# Emoji special characters are not rendered in Pillow

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I have some code:

```
text = str(input())
text_font = ImageFont.truetype(f"{os.getcwd()}{media_content_dir}Inter-Regular.otf", 17)
draw.text((235, 120), text, font=text_font, fill=(182, 182, 182))
```

Result of "  normal text ‍️" would be this:
[image]

What can I do about it? This works with any font, even the system one.

Comment: Does `Inter-Regular.otf` have those characters? Note that if you use this font in another application, it may render the emojis by falling back to a system font for missing characters. See [this answer for how to merge a font with a font that has emoji.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71654651/530160)

Comment: There are still no these symbols and most emoji. Even if I use the default font (I don’t specify it), there will be such a problem.

Comment: 1) you will need to identify fonts that have the necessary glyphs, subset those fonts, and merge them. 2) depending on complexity of the emoji, you may need to use libraqm with pillow.